# NHibernate Web Application - Managing User Preferences

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, user-preferences

I've got a web application with an NHibernate Data Access Layer.  I have a large number of user preferences that can be stored, these are mainly booleans for example registering that a dialog has been dismissed and should not be showed again.

The problem is that with NHibernate I need to add to my database schema, and add a property to the persistent class every time a new dialog is added to register if it has been dismissed or not.

There must be an easier way.  What is it?

Comment: Um... Yeah buddy!...  Hence me coming on here and asking a question trying to establish a better way to do things!  Have you got anything constructive to contribute, or is "bleh...yuck" all you can offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to read this [post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/03/08/support-dynamic-fields-with-nhibernate-and-.net-4.0.aspx) by Ayende, basically allowing for dynamic fields

> A common theme in many application is
>   the need to support custom / dynamic
>   fields. In other words, the system
>   admin may decide that the Customer
>   needs to have a few additional fields
>   that aren’t part of the mainline
>   development.

Also read Ayende's last comment

> - You can put a collection in a dynamic property.
> - You can edit the configuration programatically

**Edit** For some reason I have just realised that I have answered this question that is over one year old! Got no idea how I got here! Answer is still a good one though

Answer (score 2):

You could use a settings table to store the preferences and add a value for every dialog:

Table Settings
Id, UserId, DialogName, Value

1, 1, FirstDialog, True

2, 1, SecondDialog, False

3, 2, FirstDialog, False

4, 2, SecondDialog, False