# Managing sessions for a singleton entity with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, singleton

Recently I've been integrating NHibernate into our server application that exposes multiple services. The core service manages multiple instances of a class, and I  understood that it is recommended to use the session-per-request pattern. So far so good.

One of the other services is a Site Settings service, which effectively manages a singleton: there is only a single instance of SiteSettings. I can follow the session-per-request pattern with this service as well, but it seems odd. Do I really need to create a new session for each request here? Why not create a single session for the service and keep using it? One of the advantages of the session-per-request pattern is that the session does not eventually cache all objects in the model. However, since I will only ever load a single instance in the session, I think this should not be a concern. Would I be better off using IStatelessSession rather than ISession?

Are there other reasons to use session-per-request here? One concern that comes to mind is what happens in case of a disconnection to the DB. Can I keep using the same session even after a DB error?

As an aside, I was thinking of storing each setting in its own column, which means I have to update the schema as settings are changed. I found this post: [NHibernate Web Application - Managing User Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929942/nhibernate-web-application-managing-user-preferences), where one of the comments is against using a table to store such configuration settings. I'm having a hard time coming up with alternatives (short of serializing the whole class and storing it as a blob). Are there different approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sessions aren't thread safe so I think you'd want more than one for your singleton

> Can I keep using the same session even after a DB error?

No, presumably that would throw an exception and you're not supposed to reuse sessions after an exception.  IMHO you should stick with the session per request pattern.

> Are there different approaches?

Can you use a different row per config setting?  So your User object would have a child collection of UserSetting objects.  Each UserSetting would just be a key value pair.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My Site Settings class uses locks so that only one request is proceesed concurrently, but the DB error argument settles the doubt.

Comment: Using a row-per-config is interesting. It seems less type-safe, though (i.e. all values will be strings, unless I create a different column for each possible type).